# LibGDX compiling html error when using screens

Tags: gwt, libgdx, webgl

I have had quite an annoying issue that occurs when running the html web app in superDev mode in libgdx. I have successfully ran it multiple times, with it compiling perfectly. However, I ran into a major issue when I started to try to set a screen in the main application, the html program compiles fine, that is until, I try to set the screen.

Answer (score 0):

turns out, all that I had to do was make a simple change to the source path in the core xml file, I changed it from `org/joltsphere/main` to `org/joltsphere`
I guess it made it more generalized, 
or maybe that was how I fixed the asset folder not loading...

Comment: sorry if this is kinda poor quality, I just felt like someone might find this information useful